# Executable Jar, packaged resources pass to command

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm creating my java program that executes some command on the pc (it runs imagemagick for instance).

I have no problems with that and I'm done with the programming part; in my src I added a resource folder that contains some files I use in the calls to imagemagick, souch as ttf fonts and icc profiles: I want them to be there so everything is in the same package and it increases the protability.
In eclipse I'm doing the tests and I have no problems running the program. In it I have the following line:

```
String colorprofileString = MyClass.class.getResource("resources/srgb.icc").toString().replace("file:/", "");
```

that gives me path to the resource file as something like `C:\path\to\bin\resources\srgb.icc`, which can be accessed by imagemagick `convert` to edit some pictures.
I'm using it from eclipse and it works.

Now, I created an executable jar and in it I can see the resource folder and all the file in them, but how can I use them? The call to imagemagick is `String CMD="C:\path\to\im\convert.exe sourceimg.jpg -profile" + colorprofileString + "targetimg.jpg"`.

I'm not able to figure out how to fix it or if there is another way to do that!

Thank you very much for your help,

Mirko

Comment: External processes won't be able to access the embedded resources, you will most likely need to extract the resource to some location of the hard disk.  You can use `Class#getResourceAsStream` and simply copy the `InputStream` to some `OutputStream` which represents a file on the disk, you can then use the path to this file as the parameter to the process

Comment: Thank you! I did what you suggested by copying everything in a temp folder. I tried that and I'm in the following condition: `InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/srgb.icc");` which works if I run it in eclipse, but it doesen't work if I run with the executable jar executable: I get a `stream` which is `null` unfortunately.

Comment: Then it sounds like the resources are not be included within the jar. You unzip the jar fle (it's just a zip file) and check its contents

Comment: They are.
The class is under `org/my/context/MyClass.class` and the resource file is under `org/my/context/resources/srgb.icc` althougth I used `InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/srgb.icc");`
The icon is working and it uses `myFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MyClass.class.getResource("resources/icon.png")));`

Comment: The use the path `/org/my/context/resources/srgb.icc` instead

Comment: Good, thanks. I tried without the leading / and I got problems, but using it made it work!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the "file" may not be available as a file. Remember you are dealing with classes and resources that may be part of a JAR file or other kind of resource. The classloader does not have to provide a file handle to the resource, for example the jar file may not have been expanded into individual files in the file system.

Anything you can do by getting a java.io.File could be done by copying the stream out into a temporary file and doing the same, if a java.io.File is absolutely necessary

Comment: Thank you!
So I worked in the direction of copying everything in a temp folder.
I tried that and I'm in the following condition:
`InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/srgb.icc");` which works if I run it in eclipse, but it doesen't work if I run with the executable jar executable: I get a `stream` which is `null` unfortunately